# Serialize vector of struct for flatbuffer in Java

Tags: java, struct, flatbuffers

I am looking for an example of using vector of struct in flatbuffer in java. I tried looking at tutorial and https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/samples/SampleBinary.java
But so far have not found any good example. In tutorial https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html
the code is

```
Monster.startPathVector(fbb, 2);
Vec3.createVec3(builder, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
Vec3.createVec3(builder, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f);
int path = fbb.endVector();
```

But it does not say when and how fbb is created. Any input would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of that the referred .java files are located in https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/tree/master/tests/MyGame/Example ?

Comment: @tevemadar which file in particular are you referring to ?